# Launch Chrome from cmd, group icons

Tags: windows-7, command-line, google-chrome

I can launch 2 Chrome windows as apps as follows:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/app1" --app="http://yahoo.com"
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/app2" --app="http://google.com"
```

Windows will see these as 2 different apps, and hence they'll have their own icon on the taskbar and won't be grouped. Is there a way to pass an id as an argument to both calls s.t. they'll be considered the same app, and hence Windows will group them?

I think the AppUserModelID is what Windows uses to determine grouping, but I can't seem to find a way to force the 2 calls to use same one.

**Edit:** seems related to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91650, but that's a closed issue now. Is anyone aware of a workaround?

**Edit2:** the top answer is useful, but still looking for an automated solution.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the spawned Chrome windows are created with a different App ID,
so Microsoft's taskbar will not combine them.

I don't know of a general and automatic solution, but I know of a manual one
of combining these two icons into one. But it needs to be executed manually
each time the windows are launched.

The tool I used was
[7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)
version 5.7.1.2 which is still in beta but works on Windows 10.

I have launched 7+ Taskbar Tweaker and needed to set the following options for it
to work:

[image]

The taskbar looked like this after the two Start commands were launched:

[image]

I then dragged one of the Chrome icons on top of the other using the right mouse
button (the left button is intercepted by Windows) to achieve this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. This is definitely useful. Ideally I'm still looking for an automated solution, but I'll certainly try this. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Tested this now, and it works. I found [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/win7appid) nice utility which should normally automate this process, but as someone points out in the Chrome bugreport I added to the OP, it doesn't work for Chrome. Hence still looking for an automated solution.

Comment: By curiosity I have taken a look at how 7+ Taskbar Tweaker manages to combine icons, and found that it sets their AppUserModelID (App ID) to be the same. Unfortunately, the functions involved can only be invoked from inside the process. The solution by 7+ Taskbar Tweaker is by injecting a DLL into all the processes on the taskbar. Not simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

When I execute your script it opens in new window and is grouped in taskbar

[image: screen]

check if you have the taskbar grouping on

[image: setting]

 Edit: couldn find how to open the old menu, but in the new one it looks like this and you open it by right clicking on an empty space on your task bar and clicking on properties or taskbar settings
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems like your screenshot shows yahoo.com twice. Did you by any chance copy the first line of my script twice? Because the URL is the same, the windows are in your case grouped, I think, as I've noticed the same when I tested it. I had already checked the setting you're referring to, and it was already set to "Always combine, hide labels".